# How to create 2D array dynamically with the ES6 approach?

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, refactoring, 2d

I've been trying to create 2D arrays from an array dynamically with a function; however, I couldn't break out of the ES3 old school approach. Does anybody know how to refactor the following code using the ES6 approach?

```
const nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
const letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']; 

function create2D(arr,set) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=set) {
    const rows = arr.slice(i,i+set);
    result.push(rows);
  }
  return result;
}  

console.log(create2D(nums,4)); // [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ] ]
console.log(create2D(letters,3)); // [ [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'd', 'e', 'f' ], [ 'g', 'h', 'i' ] ]
```

I've only gotten this far with "reduce" and couldn't find out how to replicate the addition assignment "i+=set" from the for loop. This is what I have so far...

```
function create2D(arr,set) {
  return arr.reduce((result,item,i) => {
    result.push(arr.slice(i,i+set));
    return result;
  },[]);
}

console.log(create2D(nums, 4)); // [ [1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 4, 5],[3, 4, 5, 6], ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. Just need to modify it slightly:

```js
const nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
const letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']; 

function create2D(arr,set) {
  return arr.reduce((result,item,i) => {
    let startVal = i*set //We want to jump through the startPoints. Not iterate through them all
    if (startVal < arr.length-1) { 
      result.push(arr.slice(startVal,startVal+set));
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log(create2D(nums, 4)); // [ [1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 4, 5],[3, 4, 5, 6], ...]

console.log(create2D(nums, 3));

console.log(create2D(letters, 3));
```

Comment: Thank you Omar for sharing your knowledge with me in such a prompt reply. Through you I've learned how to skip indices in ES6 --> "i * set". Nevertheless, I've refactored the code slightly and realized that there in no need to subtract 1 in the condition and it would still work --> "if (index < arr.length) ... " Once again, thanks you Omar and sorry that I don't have enough reputations to up vote your reply.

Comment: @noirsociety Glad that it helped. I get that you're doing this to be able to better understand ES6, but personally, I feel that there was nothing wrong with your old school approach. Simple, clear, code should always be the priority imo, and old school works pretty well for stuff like this. No worries about the upvote, but if it's helped you, then please mark it as accepted. :)